# Enable both ident and md5 authentication in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, fedora

On Fedora 12, I'm setting up a test database for myself, and pg_hba.conf contains the following by default:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               ident
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               ident
```

I want to enable md5 logins so the PostgreSQL user named 'foo' can access the database named 'foo'.  However, when I add this line and restart postgres:

```
local   foo         foo                               md5
```

Running psql -U 'foo' with my regular user account still yields the message:

```
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "foo"
```

I have to remove the first local line (which has ident) before I can log in via md5 to 'foo'.

How can I enable md5 authentication for 'foo' while keeping ident authentication like I already have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html indicates that the order of entries maters, specifically:

> Since the pg_hba.conf records are
>   examined sequentially for each
>   connection attempt, the order of the
>   records is significant. Typically,
>   earlier records will have tight
>   connection match parameters and weaker
>   authentication methods, while later
>   records will have looser match
>   parameters and stronger authentication
>   methods. For example, one might wish
>   to use trust authentication for local
>   TCP/IP connections but require a
>   password for remote TCP/IP
>   connections. In this case a record
>   specifying trust authentication for
>   connections from 127.0.0.1 would
>   appear before a record specifying
>   password authentication for a wider
>   range of allowed client IP addresses.

(so try reversing the order - put the line you are adding at the top)